# Starting navigation in Waze with Android's Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a simple Android app which should be able to allow navigation between 2 `GeoPoint`'s.

I can easily display a `GeoPoint` on Waze, writing this small piece of code:

```
String uri = "waze://?ll=40.761043, -73.980545&z=10";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

But, what I really need is a way to display navigation directions between 2 points.
I've tried to locate the correct `BroadcastReciever` in the Waze source, but I stopped follow when it got to native calls (JNI) because I have no idea where the actual call is... I reached only to the `URIHandler` signature, with no success finding the implementation...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this is still relevant you can use this:

```
String uri = "geo: latitude,longtitude";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter this so it will only start Waze? Because when I try it it gives the user an option to go to Google Earth instead.
Google earth won't offer navigation so it's a crappy experience.

Comment: @Ankhwatcher .. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: For anyone wanting to filter Activities, you can use PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(...) to filter out the Activities you don't want. Search Google for more info.

Comment: Does not work for Waze currently, Android 13 (API level 31 for app):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145009/android-generic-way-to-reliably-start-navigation-activity-using-default-app

Answer (score 17):

Fix you uri to:

```
String uri = "waze://?ll=40.761043, -73.980545&navigate=yes";
```

(added navigate=yes) and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for this! BTW, do you have any source?

Comment: I get you mean source code? It's pretty much the source code from Ami's answer, just replace the URI. If you have a more specific request, please specify.

Comment: I meant if there's any doc from Waze for this intent, I'd like to have the link

Comment: New waze dev link is here https://developers.google.com/waze   . It is stil unclear to me if it supports StartActivityForResult

Answer (score 3):

Today's `Waze` base url is `https://waze.com/ul` so to navigate you have to use

```
https://waze.com/ul?ll=45.6906304,-120.810983&navigate=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do [kotlin]:

```
fun openWaze(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    packageManager?.let {
        val url = "waze://?ll=$latitude,$longitude&navigate=yes"
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        intent.resolveActivity(it)?.let {
            startActivity(intent)
        } ?: run {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.noWazeAppFound, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Google doc about working with Waze you can use code below to open waze from your android app:

```
try {
    // Launch Waze to look for Hawaii:
    String url = "https://waze.com/ul?ll=40.761043,-73.980545&navigate=yes";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // If Waze is not installed, open it in Google Play:
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.waze"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```