# Android: Generic way to reliably start navigation activity using default app

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, url-scheme

I know, this question is as old as Android is (almost), and there are many questions on the subject here on SO and elsewhere. However, I have not found an up-to-date, working solution to this problem:

Is there a generic way, to open a app for navigation, using a generic URI scheme that does not specify a specific nav app, that actually works for the main nav apps out there?

I am running these tests on a physical device with Android 13 (Pixel 6). App is on targer API 31 (Android 12).

First, here is proof from a debug session that the Uri is correct and so is the coordinate:

[image]

## URI scheme "geo":

```
Uri gmmIntenturi = Uri.parse("geo:q=" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntenturi);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

**Results:**

- Waze:

  - I get an error saying "Something went wrong: Apologies, we can only provide routes under 3000 miles at this point. We're working on increasing it": 
    [image]
  - The distance in this case is 560 km flight distance or 672 km driving
- Google Maps:

  - Opens Google Maps/Nav, shows my current location, no route

## URI scheme "google.navigation":

```
Uri gmmIntenturi= Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntenturi);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Results:

- Waze:

  - Opens app, shows my current location
  - Does not seem to care at all about the location in the URI
- Google Nav:

  - Opens app, and correctly shows a route to the location in the URI

**Is there a better way to reliably open the default navigation app (or show user a list of nav apps to choose from), where the default/chosen app automatically navigates to the given coordinates from the current position of the device?**

Comment: I think your problem here is that the URIs you're using aren't being handled "acceptably" by some of the apps, and there's no way to know if that will happen until the `Intent` has been consumed by whichever app was chosen to handle it. As far as I know, there's no way for an app to go "oops my bad" and rebroadcast the `Intent` so another app can take a crack at it (and no guarantee these apps think they're doing anything wrong anyway). If an app says it can handle that URI (through its `intent-filter`s) then it'll be considered as an option.

Comment: Right, but I dont really get it. I read that using geo: and google.navigation should work, and the apps appear in the list, indicating that they do listen to intents with those Uri schemes. They open, but then nothing happens. So, I am really looking for a way to do this properly...

Comment: I mean it seems like the Android side of things is working fine? You have a URI, some apps claim to be able to handle it, it gets passed over to them... once an app gets the URI, if it doesn't handle it the way you'd expect then that's either an issue with the app, or the URI itself. The Android system can't do anything about that, and it doesn't have any way to "test" apps to see if they really can handle an Intent before deciding which one should do it / which should be displayed. I don't know anything about the URI schemes here but I'd look into that and what's supported by each app

Comment: Just quickly looking around (this is probably what you're talking about) there's people asking the same question 4 years ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/47496232/13598222 It looks like the apps themselves are just unreliable, especially with "standard" formats. Maybe nothing's changed! If nobody's following a single standard I don't know if there's much you can do about that - all the solutions seem to be about targetting a specific app directly

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was afraid of =(

Answer (score 4):

My question was:

> Is there a better way to reliably open the default navigation app (or
> show user a list of nav apps to choose from), where the default/chosen
> app automatically navigates to the given coordinates from the current
> position of the device?

The quick answer is: **no**

It seems that you need to manually add different navigation Intent, specifically designed for each nav app so it works as expected.

Creating a "chooser", seems to be pretty efficient, as you can add code for all nav apps you want, but only those installed on device will actually show up in the chooser. This is some code for that:

```
public static void startNavigation(Context context, double latitude, double longitude)
{
    Uri uriWaze = Uri.parse("https://waze.com/ul?ll=" + latitude + "," +  longitude + "&navigate=yes");
    Intent intentWaze = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriWaze);
    intentWaze.setPackage("com.waze");

    String uriGoogle = "google.navigation:q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    Intent intentGoogleNav = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriGoogle));
    intentGoogleNav.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

    String title = "Choose nav";
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentGoogleNav, title);
    Intent[] arr = new Intent[1];
    arr[0] = intentWaze;
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arr);
    context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```